# Cannot convert PIL image from Paint.NET to numpy array

Tags: python

I am getting a `ValueError` in numpy when performing operations on images. The problem seems to be that the images edited by Paint.NET are missing the RGB dimension when opened using PIL and converted to a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PIL is giving you a 861x1091 image when you are expecting an 861x1091x3 image, that is almost certainly because it is a palette image - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621) for explanation.

The simplest thing to do, if you want a 3-channel RGB image rather than a single channel palette image is to convert it to RGB when you open it:

```
im = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
```